# Поиск в текстовом файле предложений с заданной подстрокой

Tags: c++, visual-c++

У меня получилось сделать поиск подстроки в строке, но в предложении не получается. Как сделать поиск в предложении? (Visual Studio 2010)

```
char text[1024];
char text1[1024];
    ifstream file("text.txt");
if (file.is_open()) {
    cout<<"Введите текст для поиска: ";
    cin>>text1;
    while (file.getline(text, 1024)) {      
        if (strstr(text, text1))
        cout<<text<<endl;
    }
    file.close();
} else 
    cout<<"Ошибка! Файла не существует!"<<endl;
```

Comment: Скачать весь текст. Разбить на предложения. А в предложениях уже искать.

Comment: Как программе понять, что это предложения, записать это никак не могу.

Comment: Если нашли точку, вопросительный знак или восклицательный знак, то это конец предложения. Вот и делите текст по концу предложения. Многоточие не рассматриваем для простоты.

Comment: Вот так например https://ideone.com/CB1tgV . Тут ещё пробелы в начале предложения, но это вы уже сами сможете обработать.

Comment: У меня получилось определить, что является предложением и вывести строку с этим предложением. В текстовом файле в первой строке у меня записано 2 предложения, во 2 и 3 строке по 1 предложению. Если я ввожу какое то слово из предложения 1 строки, то выводится вся строка целиком (т.е. оба предложения). Не могу сделать, чтобы она вывела нужное предложение.

Comment: вот `if (file.is_open()) {
 cout<<"Введите текст для поиска: ";
 cin>>text1;
 while (file.getline(text, 1024)) {
  size_t n=0;
  for (const char *p = text, *first; *p;) {
   while (*p == ' ' || *p == '\t') ++p;
   if ( n==0 ) first = p;
   ++n;
   while (*p && !(*p == ' ' || *p == '\t' || *p == '.')) ++p;
   if (*p == '\0' || *p == '.') {
    while (*p == '\t' || *p == '.') ++p;   
    n=0;
    if (strstr(text, text1))
     cout.write(first, p - first)<<"\n";
   }
  }
 }
 file.close();
}`

Comment: Эти комментарии хорошо бы добавить в текст вопроса.

Comment: Особо не проверял, но похоже  даже работает http://rextester.com/ONHUAA29520

Comment: Да, все работает, спасибо большое!